# Aggregation of user defined types in PostgreSQL with postgresql client under Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I would be grateful for your advice.
I use postgres 16 and postgresql client under node.js
There is a table with a user defined type:

```
CREATE TYPE my_type AS ENUM ('value1', 'value2');

CREATE TABLE table2
(
 id bigint PRIMARY KEY,
 t1_id ...,
 field1 my_type default 'value1'
 field2 integer
);
```

I want use it in the join:

```
SELECT
   table1.field1 as t1f1, ...
   array_agg(table2.field1) as t2f1,
   array_agg(table2.field2) as t2f2,
   array_agg(table3.field1) as t3f1,
   ...
FROM table1 
   LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.t1_id = table1.id
   LEFT JOIN table 3 ON table3.t1_id=table1.id
   ...
GROUP BY table1.id
```

But for some reason I get the result for this column (**t2f1** in this examle) as a string with a raw postgres array, and not a regular array like the other columns:

```
[
  {
    t1f1: "blah-blah",
    t2f1: "{NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL}",
    t2f2: [NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL],
    t3f1: [NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL],
  }
]
```

So the question is how to force the postgres client handle the enum correctly.

Comment: can't you just cast the inputted value to text? array_agg(table2.field1::text) as t2f1,

Comment: I can, of course, but I’m interested in the root cause of this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that [node-postgres knows how to parse the representation for a few built-in types](https://node-postgres.com/features/types) like `text[]` or `integer[]`, but not for the `my_type[]` - it doesn't know that `my_type` is an enum, nor that the type id postgres sends back as part of the result refers to an array type. It just defaults to the string deserialisation.

You can work around this by adding a cast to your SQL (`array_agg(table2.field1::text)` or `array_agg(table2.field1)::text[]`).

But if you actually want `pg` to correctly parse any occurrence of values of this type, you need to [use `pg-types`](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types) to set up a type parser. Start executing

```sql
SELECT typname, oid, typarray FROM pg_type WHERE typname = 'my_type';
```

or

```sql
SELECT 'my_type[]'::regtype::oid;
```

to find the `typarray` oid of your enum type. Then in your code, when setting up `pg`, tell it to parse data of your `my_type[]` the same as it would parse `text[]`:

```js
const OID_ARRAY_TEXT = 1009;
const OID_ARRAY_MY_TYPE = …; // whatever oid number you got

pg.types.setTypeParser(OID_ARRAY_MY_TYPE, pg.types.getTypeParser(OID_ARRAY_TEXT));
```

See also issues [node-pg-types#56](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types/issues/56) and [#68](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types/issues/68).

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer.